# I get 404 when I try to login ever since I changed the permalink

Tags: login, 404-error

This is the [website](http://wayfaroutadventures.com)

This is what the login http://wayfaroutadventures.com/blog/wp-admin/&reauth=1">looks like now

Basically here's what happened:

I had `www.mysite.com/blog` as the permalink instead of `www.mysite.com`, and `/blog` wouldn't go away. So then I changed it so it was `.com` without blog and it not won't let me login or anything, gives me a 404. I'm scared because I think I seriously screwed up and I don't know how to fix it! How do I get it so I can login again. I don't even care if its `/blog` anymore. I just want my site back.

Answer (score 0):

You can still get to your login page: http://wayfaroutadventures.com/blog/wp-login.php You probably haven't done any serious damage.

Login to your site over FTP or using some file manager provided by your host and add:

> ```
> define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress');
> define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/wordpress');
> ```
>
> See:
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29

Of course, the addresses need to match exactly what you had before you changed things. That should get you operating again.

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29